# Define subset in Cplex

Tags: set, cplex, indices

I have a set of doors. And this set include 2 set: set of receiving doors and set of shipping doors.
How can I define this 2 subsets in Cplex?

In detail:

D: set of available doors

Din, which belongs to D: set of receiving doors

Dout, which belongs to D: set of shipping doors

```
int numDoors=5;
range Doors=1..numDoors;
```

Comment: Can you show any of the code that you have created so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
int numDoors=5;
range Doors=1..numDoors;

{int} D=asSet(Doors);

{int} Din={first(D)} union {last(D)};

{int} Dout=D diff Din;

execute
{
  writeln("D=",D);
  writeln("Din=",Din);
  writeln("Dout=",Dout);
}
```

gives

```
D= {1 2 3 4 5}
Din= {1 5}
Dout= {2 3 4}
```